# Creating a class for a single function - good design

Tags: c#

I'm converting a C program to C#.
The program uses a function called PatternRecognition(image, param1, param2, param3, etc.. many others) which cannot be included in the "Image" class.
In C# I could create a class, say PatternRecognitor, with one method, for example Execute(image, param1, param2, param3, etc.. many others)

My question is: since I don't like to manage all those parameters when the function is called in several parts of the program, **is a better design** to make them members of the PatternRecognitor class, and set them with setter/getters functions? (or just a "SetParam" function?)

Comment: Side note: consider reading [Working effectively with legacy code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052) as it covers a lot of topics (including this) that you may hit on the way.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a lot of parameters that change with calls to a function. It's often practical to package those parameters in their own class.

You could create something like this.

```
public class RecognizerOptions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ....
}

public class PatternRecognizer
{
    public void Execute(RecognizerOptions options)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

You can also create a factory class for the `RecognizerOptions` to make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Using a `RecognizerOptions` for the function parameter solves the issue by itself -- there is now no need for a dedicated `PatternRecognizer` to contain the function.

Comment: @nmclean separating the business logic from the problem of to many options makes maintenance easier, and the code more readable. It's not really a solution to a problem, but more a coding practice or design pattern.

Comment: Yes, wrapping up the options in a class gives the maintenance / readability benefits, but the second class, `PatternRecognizer`, is superfluous. We can just change the `PatternRecognition` method of `Image` to accept a `RecognizerOptions`.